# Thousands of UITableViewCellSeperatorView in UITableView with custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Since I use xCode 6 beta 5 `UITableViews` with nib files for custom cells shows only a small stripe of the cell on the left and the rest is grey. When I open up the View Debugger it says that there are thousands of `_UITableViewCellSeperatorViews` in my `TableView`. 
Here is the class of the `TableViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TestTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "newTestCell")
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newTestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestTableViewCell
    cell.loadData("Test")
    return cell
}
```

Here is the class of the cell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!

func loadData(text: String) {
    someLabel.text = text
}
```

Now I've got a picture of the TableView in the View Debugger:

[image: TableView in Debugger]

Comment: can you post the exact message you get in console (debugger).

Comment: I don't get any error or message in the console

Comment: I had the same problem with Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed puzzling. Here is how I fixed it: just after registering the nib add

```
tableView.rowHeight = 44 // or whatever
```

Comment: Can we consider that it's an IOS 8 or Xcode 6 bug ?